# Change cluster icon in google maps on xamarin.forms (android)

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use googlemaps.clustering in my app. How can I change cluster icons? Like this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVDWU.png)

Comment: Create a `DefaultClusterRenderer` sublcass and override `OnBeforeClusterRendered`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin this article could help you